# How to detect Collision In jQuery during animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to detect the collision during the animation. I was trying on the button click the collision was working on buttton click but when I am doing the animation randomly the collision is not working

this is my animate function . I am getting new position and placing in a variable

```
function animateDiv(){

var newq = makeNewPosition();
var oldq = $('.block').offset();
var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

$('.block').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){

  animateDiv(); 

});
```

In this animate function two more functions are using calculate speed and make new position

```
function calcSpeed(prev, next) {
var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);
var greatest = x > y ? x : y;
var speedModifier = .8;
var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);
return speed; 
}


function makeNewPosition(){

// Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
var h = $(window).height() + 500;
var w = $(window).width() +500;

var nh = Math.floor(0 * h);
var nw = Math.floor(50 * w);

return [nh,nw];    

}

function checkCollisions() {
                var box = $(".bomb")[0];

                var pos = getPositions(box);
                var pos2 = getPositions(this);
                var horizontalMatch = comparePositions(pos[0], pos2[0]);
                var verticalMatch = comparePositions(pos[1], pos2[1]);

                var match = horizontalMatch && verticalMatch;

                if (match) { 
                change();
                //animateDiv();
                $("#left,#right,#up,#down").hide();
                $(".block").animate({ "left": "-=500px","top":"+=300px" }, "slow", checkCollisions);
                }



            }
```

And this is my check collision function

html code is given below.

```
   <div class="block" id="divFirst">A</div>
    <div class="bomb" id="divSecond">B</div>
    <div id="buket" class="buket"></div>
```

Comment: How about using [`progress` event](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options)

Comment: What is comparePositions? I don't see that function anywhere.